# Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, antd

Whenever I wanna use an `Ant design Component` I catch an error with this title:

```
antd.min.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (antd.min.js:23)
    at t (antd.min.js:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (antd.min.js:31)
    at t (antd.min.js:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (antd.min.js:50)
    at t (antd.min.js:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (antd.min.js:7)
    at t (antd.min.js:7)
    at antd.min.js:7
    at antd.min.js:7
```

I use the latest version (3.7.3)

In this part I've used `Layout Component` of ant design:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { Layout, Menu, Icon } from 'antd';

const { Header, Content, Footer, Sider } = Layout;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Layout>
    <Sider
      breakpoint="lg"
      collapsedWidth="0"
      onBreakpoint={(broken) => { console.log(broken); }}
      onCollapse={(collapsed, type) => { console.log(collapsed, type); }}
    >
      <div className="logo" />
      <Menu theme="dark" mode="inline" defaultSelectedKeys={['4']}>
        <Menu.Item key="1">
          <Icon type="user" />
          <span className="nav-text">nav 1</span>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="2">
          <Icon type="video-camera" />
          <span className="nav-text">nav 2</span>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="3">
          <Icon type="upload" />
          <span className="nav-text">nav 3</span>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="4">
          <Icon type="user" />
          <span className="nav-text">nav 4</span>
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    </Sider>
    <Layout>
      <Header style={{ background: '#fff', padding: 0 }} />
      <Content style={{ margin: '24px 16px 0' }}>
        <div style={{ padding: 24, background: '#fff', minHeight: 360 }}>
          content
        </div>
      </Content>
      <Footer style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
        Ant Design ©2018 Created by Ant UED
      </Footer>
    </Layout>
  </Layout>,
  document.getElementById('main'));
```

but I unfortunately face with error, while I just copied the [antdesign](https://ant.design) code. I don't know what is the problem, please help me.

Comment: can you please post some example code? Stack trace might not be enough. Do take a look at our https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve guide, it helps us help you!

Comment: @dubes The post is edited

Comment: Sorry my answer was wrong, I will see your problem and try to answer it later

Comment: @MShoaib91 Looking forward to hearing from you ASAP. Thanks

Comment: current synyax is fine too but try just `import React from 'react';` Also can you post your package.json and webpack.config files will be helpful

Comment: I don't know what is the webpack configuration! and I don't have any files like this. You can see [my repository](https://github.com/mostafaghadimi/Kheft "Mostafa Ghadimi's Github Repository ")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my gulp and browserify configuration. I tried to change the technology I'm using and I switch to `webpack` with many more benefits than gulp that can be read in the following link:

[gulp vs browserify vs webpack](https://www.toptal.com/front-end/webpack-browserify-gulp-which-is-better)

Answer (score 11):

A bit late to this, but this sounds like a typescript error.  If anyone else comes across this change

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
```

to

```
import * as React from 'react'
```

Comment: Friend I was about to cry all my tears on this and then I found your comment. Thanks <3

Comment: Why this fix the issue? And is there a way to fix the issue and still use the first way?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't see your codebase but I guess the reason is that you are trying to import on demand, but didn't use babel-plugin-import in your project.

Please refer to the [Import on Demand](https://ant.design/docs/react/getting-started#Import-on-Demand) section in the docs.

If you are using create-react-app, you can check the instructions [here](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app#Use-babel-plugin-import).

Comment: I don't know how to `import on demand`. I've read the instructions but I'm using gulp and browserify and have know idea how to fix it

Comment: Did you try to add [babel-plugin-import](https://github.com/ant-design/babel-plugin-import)?

Comment: I dont' know how!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about **Ant design components**, but from the stack trace that you've provided, I can say that the `antd` object is not present. It may be due to `antd` not loading properly. I would suggest you to check if `antd` is being loaded or not by trying to `console.log(antd)` or whatever is the name of the object.

Also, kindly provide the related code to let us help you better.

Comment: It returns undefined truly, because we don't import `antd` individually, we just import some components from it. As you can see I've imported `import React, {Component} from 'react';` ... so it returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this error the try these two ways as well. It will work:

**Error:**
[image]

**Solution 1:**

```
import React from "react";

class Greetings extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>working</div>;
  }
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Greetings extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>working</div>;
  }
}
```